# What if I'm training a model that has two acceptable answers for a situation?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to train a model to find a blue dot in an image. But around 30% of the time, there are two blue dots, and in these cases, I would be happy with it finding either one.

I don't want to criticize the machine for picking the "wrong dot", because that's not important. I just need it to find either dot.

I have a list of the blue dot co-ordinate(s) in each image, hand-labelled.

I'm not sure how to train it to do this.

I'm using TensorFlow, with keras, and I can share my code for finding a blue dot when I ignore the images with two, but it wouldn't be particularly helpful without the dataset, which is...large.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a good answer, but it's what I landed on. Instead of giving "the x,y coordinate" of "the blue dot". I instead produced a new image that had blue pixels where the blue dots in the input were, and then just wrote a dumb algorithm to bruteforce every pixel in the image to find the blue ones, and put those into a normal list.